# Should I use boost fast pool allocator for following?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, malloc

I have a server that throughout the course of 24 hours keeps adding new items to a set.  Elements are not deleted over the 24 period, just new elements keep getting inserted.

Then at end of period the set is cleared, and new elements start getting added again for another 24 hours.

Do you think a fast pool allocator would be useful here as to reuse the memory and possibly help with fragmentation?

The set grows to around 1 million elements.  Each element is about 1k.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all.  You don't need a "fast allocator" to allocate memory 12 times a second.  That problem was solved 50 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly unlikely …but you are of course free to test it in your program.

For a collection of that size and allocation pattern (more! more! more! + grow! grow! grow!), you should use an array of vectors. Just keep it in contiguous blocks and `reserve()` when they are created and you never need to reallocate/resize or waste space and bandwidth traversing lists. vector is going to be best for your memory layout with a collection that large. Not one big vector (which would take a long time to resize), but several vectors, each which represent chunks (ideal chunk size can vary by platform -- I'd start with 5MB each and measure from there). If you follow, you see there is no need to resize or reuse memory; just create an allocation every few minutes for the next `N` objects -- there is no need for high frequency/speed object allocation and recreation.

The thing about a pool allocator would suggest you want a lot of objects which have discontiguous allocations, lots of inserts and deletes like a list of big allocations -- this is bad for a few reasons. If you want to create an implementation which optimizes for contiguous allocation at this size, just aim for the blocks with vectors approach. Allocation and lookup will both be close to minimal. At that point, allocation times should be tiny (relative to the other work you do). Then you will also have nothing unusual or surprising about your allocation patterns. However, the fast pool allocator suggests you treat this collection as a list, which will have terrible performance for this problem.

Once you implement that block+vector approach, a better performance comparison (at that point) would be to compare boost's pool_allocator vs std::allocator. Of course, you could test all three, but memory fragmentation is likely going to be reduced far more by that block of vectors approach, if you implement it correctly. [Reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html):

> If you are seriously concerned about performance, use fast_pool_allocator when dealing with containers such as std::list, and use pool_allocator when dealing with containers such as std::vector.