# Very fast object allocator for small object of same size

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, boost, stl

I just have to write some code that has to have best performance.

Requirements:

I need a very fast object allocator for quick creation of object. My object as only 3 doubles in it. Allocation and deallocation will occurs one object at a time only.

I made a lots of research and come up with:

```
std::vector<MyClass, boost::fast_pool_allocator<MyClass>>
```

I wonder (in 2014-07):

- Does stl have something equivalent to boost::boost:fast_pool_allocator ?
- Is there a better solution to what I have found ?

There is additional information to answer some comments:

- The code will be used to optimize my algorithm for: [Code Project article on Convex Hull](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775753/A-new-Convex-Hull-Algorithm-and-its-implementation)
- I need to convert C# code to C or C++ to improve performance. I should compete against another algorithm written in pure "C". I just discover that my comparison chart in my article have errors because I tested against code compiled in C for x86-Debug. In x64-release the "C" code is a lot faster (a factor of 4 to 5 times faster than in x86-debug).
- According to [This Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html) and this [Answer at StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005408/should-i-use-boost-fast-pool-allocator-for-following), boost:fast_pool_allocator seems to be the best allocator to use for small memory chunk of same size query one by one. But I would like to make sure nothing else exists that is either more standard (part of stl) or faster.
- My code will be developed on Visual Studio 2013 and target any windows platform (no phone or tablet).
- My intend is not to have fast code, it is to have the fastest code. I prefer not having too much twisted code if possible and also look for code that is maintainable (at least a minimum).
- If possible, I also would like to know the impact of using std:vector vs array (ie: []).
- For more info, you could see [Wikipedia - Object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)

Comment: Did you profile `std::vector<>` to begin with ? How do you know if one structure fits better than the others ? What is the scenario ? The context ?

Comment: No I did not profile. I did not add boost to my project yet. I'm asking because I don't know what to choose? What's the quickest way for my needs? I don't understand. What it is not clear in my question ?

Comment: I did not program in C++ for 10 years now and the only think I have found was what I present here. If stl has now a good allocator, then just tell me. I would really happy to hear it.

Comment: Allocator used for vectors doesn't really have anything to do with what kind of object you are planning on storing. (Some sort of file backed allocator aside. :-)). You will be doing only couple of allocations anyway, because vector takes swath of memory and then just fill in the objects as needed. Also please do the profiling next time, before going on about performance requirements.

Comment: @Xam, why asking to do profiling. The fastest on paper should be the fastest on code. If I try every thing and profile every thing, then it will not need to ask. I just wonder if I could have missed anything that would have been faster than what I have found. Almost every thing found dated from 5 to 10 years. Is it still valid. Does stl has made some changes to its allocator because many articles and  stackoverflow anwsers seems to recommend boost. It would be suprising that stl haven't follow what boost would have made???

Comment: You have to profile, so you don't go searching for performance where it is pointless. If you have a function that takes 0.1% of total processing time, it is kinda pointless to optimize it. If you have function that takes 90%, literally any speed-up is going to be huge. Also, again: if all you care about is a single vector with lots and lots of contained data, worrying about allocator performance is pointless, leave that for working with lists. If not and you have oodles of vectors, maybe a stateful allocator with shared memory pool could help. Then again, maybe rethinking the design would too.

Comment: The STL comes with your compiler. Different compilers have different implementations. Generally the default allocators are fine. There is no such thing as 'the fastest on paper' since 'fastest' depends on too many variables -- how exactly are you using the data structure? On what compiler? On what OS? Does the difference in performance even matter from a user's perspective? That's why profiling is valuable -- because it tells you exactly where the bottleneck is. The alternative is to assume, and assumptions about where a bottleneck is are often wrong.

Comment: @Cameron: You are simplifying the dependencies too much. Which is probably kind of the point you try to make: Performance is complex and there are too damn many dependencies to decide it without trying. Well, one *can* normally decide big-O-complexity...

Comment: build something that works, then see if it goes fast enough. I would start with plain std::vector

Comment: "The fastest on paper should be the fastest on code" - uh huh.  For some things, sure, but have you ever heard the quote *"In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. But, in practice, there is."*?  This is why we profile.  What's the downside?

Comment: I added more info in question to answer some comments. I'm a bit disappointed to see comments. I feel peoples want to answer to have easy point without knowing the answer. You need to know the implementation of allocators or dig into them to be able to answer this question. I rarely ask question where I can found my answer easily on the web. Usually my question are the result of a process of few hours of research without being able to find a satisfying answer. I could be wrong but I think that it should be like that otherwise there will be tons of duplicate questions/answers.

Comment: Instead of trying to find the fastest allocator, have you first ensured you are not reallocating unnecessarily and are using `vector` efficiently? That can improve performance by an order of magnitude, not the few percent you'll get from switching allocators

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely, boost as already made 2 special allocator to improve performance for special usage like mine. There should be a reason for it. About my code... I will do my best to make it as fast as I can, but it is not the question.

Comment: Thanks to all. You are probably right but I still think that it is valuable to know internal working of library implementation and make decision on regards to that and other possibilities before starting to code. Having good knowledge of every possibilities and their internals (libraries, own personal implementation, community code) enable us to code better from start and/or at least increase our chances to make better decision earlier.

Comment: How does `std::vector` come into the picture here? `std::vector` is a reallocating container, meaning that it cannot be used anywhere where persistent pointers are required. What am I missing here?

Comment: @AndreyT, Sorry! You are right. My initial question which I slightly modified over time was mainly divided into 2 questions which I though was not good and leads to a too much complex question to answer. I simplified but still vector seams to be not related. To make it short, all small object needed to be allocated into an array (or a vector). In fact it need to be allocated dynamically. But I also though that reallocation cost too very much and I could have better performance by allocating max size at start, and then cast reserved memory as object (big cheat to save time). Does it answer?

Comment: If you're using a std::vector then any allocator won't do much for you. They are mostly meant for containers with a lot of dynamic allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to what I was looking for was Paulo Zemek Code Project article: [O(1) Object Pool in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/746630/O-Object-Pool-in-Cplusplus).

But I finally did allocate/reserve memory of size= the maximum size possible * my object size.
Because I was not using any objects that required to live longer than my algorithm loop, I cheated by saying that location in reserved memory space was object. After my algorithm loop, I flushed the reserved memory space. It appears to me to be the fastest. Very not elegant but extremely fast and only require one allocation and one deallocation.

I was not totally satisfy with the answer, that's why I answered myself. I also added a comments to the questions about every comments and added this answer to make thinks clear. I know that my decision/implementation  was not totally in accordance with the question but I think that it should have conducted to something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Search for [memory-pool heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool). Basically, you create a heap dedicated for objects of a single size (typically powers of 2, 4 bytes, 16 bytes, etc) and allocate objects from the heap that can contain blocks of the smallest size that can fit your object in. As each heap only contains fixed-size blocks, its very easy to manage the blocks that are allocated in it, a bitmap can show you which blocks are free or in-use so insertion can be very fast (especially if you just allocate at the end and increment a pointr)

As an example, [here's one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17060/A-Fast-Efficient-Allocator-for-Small-Blocks-of-Mem), you may be able to take it and optimise it explicitly for your particular object size and requirements.

Comment: A bitmap is way too complicated, just maintain a linked list of free objects in the memory of those free objects. To free an object, you just have to adjust two pointers, to alloc one, only one pointer needs to be modified. The only special case that needs to be handled is an empty free object list.

Comment: True, it was only something that popped into my head as I was typing that might help the OP with his special requirements. If super speed is his goal then cache localisation of a bitmap might help a little. Definitely misleading for common cases though, ta.

Comment: @cmaster in what way is a bitmap too complicated?

Comment: @NickStrupat In the way that it does not readily support the operations you need. The data structure to manage the free blocks must support exactly two operations, and those with the best possible performance: 1) Add a free block, and 2) retrieve a free block (if there is a free block at all), any free block will do. The bitmap supports the first operation perfectly, but it fails at the second: To retrieve a free block, the bitmap must be *searched*. That is a way too complex operation to be fast. The linked list approach supports both operations perfectly.

Comment: A bitmap is not as fast as a linked list,  but it's definitely not complicated.  And a bitmap has a possible use case:  when the object size is smaller than the platform's pointer size (and thus an in-place linked list is not possible)

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution very useful to me: [Fast C++11 allocator for STL containers](https://github.com/moya-lang/Allocator). It slightly speeds up STL containers on VS2017 (~5x) as well as on GCC (~7x). Moreover you can manually specify grow size or if you know the maximal number of elements in your list, you can preallocate them all.